# How do I deal with Runtime Error in For Loop in Python?

Tags: python

Hi I am a Python beginner,

so I wanted to print a hallowed rectangle with *, and I wrote this:

```
m,n= int(input()), int(input())
for i in range(m):
    if (i==0 or i==m-1):
        print('*'*n)
    else:
        print('*'+" "*(n-2)+"*")
```

or either:

```
m,n= int(input()), int(input())

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
      if (i==0 or i==m-1 or j==0 or j==m-1):
          print("*",end='')
      else:
          print(" ",end='')
    print()
```

I don't know what was going wrong, but it kept telling me I've got runtime error:((

Comment: Use one code snippet for your question

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Your runtime error might have more details, you should post the entire error message as well, if relevant. Please, have a look at these guidelines on [how to ask a good received question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already.

Comment: Can you post the input you are giving and the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

Both your code snippets work fine. The only time you can get a runtime error, judging by what you gave us at this moment, is when you enter letters instead of numbers for `m` and/or `n`.